# Importing XML file into JSP project from totally different JSP project

Tags: xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have created a JSP project named 'JSTL XML 2'. I have another JSP project named '39-JSTL_XML' in the same workspace. I have added one XML file called 'UsersXML.xml' in web-content folder of '39-JSTL_XML'.

I am trying to import this xml file into the other project like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <c:import url="http://localhost:8080/39-JSTL_XML/UsersXML.xml" var="usersXML"/>
    <x:parse xml="${usersXML}" var="usersDoc" />
    <x:out select="$usersDoc/users/user[1]/name"/>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it, it gives me error that : 
"Problem accessing the absolute URL "http://localhost:8080/39-JSTL_XML/UsersXML.xml". java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/39-JSTL_XML/UsersXML.xml"

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Although I am not sure exactly what was the problem, I observed that when I ran the first project on browser by hitting it's URL, it was throwing 'path not found'. Then I simply added a sample JSP file. Added the name of that sample file in welcome-file list in 'web.xml'. And now it's working fine.